# How can i get the Payable function to send the right amount to the owner address?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, ether, payable

```
function () public payable {
    uint tokens;
    
    /// this math isnt safe 
    tokens = msg.value * 10;
    
    /// this didnt give us the address we needed
    address tokenOwner;

    
    balances[msg.sender] = safeAdd(balances[msg.sender], tokens);
    _totalSupply = safeAdd(_totalSupply, tokens);
    emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, tokens);
    tokenOwner.transfer(msg.value);

    }
```

im trying to grok how to write a function where the contract takes ETH and gives tokens back to the sender of the ETH and send the ETH to the contract owner.

I have to problems

1. It sent the wrong amount - i sent .1 ETH to the contract and it send me like 10,000,000,000,000 coins or something.
2. The tokenOwner never got the .1 ETH sent -- neither did the contract.

Any ideas where I went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not adjust the scale like this. `msg.value` is already scaled properly.

```
tokens = msg.value * 10;
```

This is useless. A `balances` mapping is usually used to track liabilities owed by the contract to other users. But you forward the funds immediately so you have no need for this.

```
balances[msg.sender] = safeAdd(balances[msg.sender], tokens);
```

It's not clear where `tokenOwner` came from.

```
tokenOwner.transfer(msg.value);
```

Try

```
contract Thing {

  address payable owner;

  function forwarder() public payable {
    owner.transfer(msg.value);
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Owner is `0x0...` because we didn't set it to anything. You could go nuts and import transferable ownership and make the owner the destination.

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract Thing is Ownable {

  function forwarder() public payable {
    payable(owner()).transfer(msg.value); // Ownable sets it in the constructor and presents an owner() function 
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: this helped a lot! was abgle to fix the token amount, and the code above helped in not getting a compile error on owner.transfer(msg.value) however the ETH seems to go to 0x00000000000000000000 and not back to the token owner contract

Comment: You have to extrapolate off of the example. Set `owner` to where it should go. I assume not `msg.sender` but also not `0.0...` as in my little sketch. That's what I meant by "It's not clear where tokenOwner came from" - I just don't know where the correct value comes from. Possibly set it up in the constructor with `Ownable`.

Comment: Is it ever bad form to code in the address implicitly into the .transfer function?

Comment: I would say "usually." There are practical reasons why it gets in the way. There are exceptions. An argument in favor of it would be gas optimization. IMHO, constants should be declared up front rather than deep in the code. Thanks for accepting my answer.